# Why didn't my code save the shifted field df.shift()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame df with several columns, say 'A','B' and 'C'. I tried to make a new column 'D' which is a shift of 'C'. There is no error but it turns out my df still have only 3 columns. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

I encounter this issue in Jupyter. With the same concept, I did try on Spyder and it somehow works. Could it be that syntax in Jupyter is different?

````
```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3), columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)
          A         B         C
0  0.921140  2.003523 -0.639205
1 -1.148732 -0.189015  0.669867
2 -0.033608 -0.423422  1.813582
3  0.643690  0.378495  0.181346
4 -1.327353  0.166061 -0.003853
5  0.522366 -1.780002 -1.609952
df['D'] = df['A'].shift()
print(df)
          A         B         C
0  0.921140  2.003523 -0.639205
1 -1.148732 -0.189015  0.669867
2 -0.033608 -0.423422  1.813582
3  0.643690  0.378495  0.181346
4 -1.327353  0.166061 -0.003853
5  0.522366 -1.780002 -1.609952
```
````

and again, I got no warning nor an error. It just ignores and my df still have the same shape as if nothing happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you post some more code, preferably with sample data?

Comment: @Chris OK added

Comment: the code works for me..make sure you didnt have any typos like dfg = or something weird..i dunno

Comment: It still works perfectly fine for me too. Try updating or reinstalling jupyter